# Client (Android) & Server (Localhost console) communication issue

Tags: java, android, client-server

I am not a seasoned Java and Android practitioner, however, I will try to explain my issue clearly.

**Non-descriptive explanation of what is needed**:

Client: Android app, Server: Localhost

Client ---> Server, i.e., clients sends something to server.

Client <--- Server

Client ---> Server

Client <--- Server

Basically what's supposed to happen is RSA key exchanged led by encrypted AES key exchange.

**Descriptive explanation**:

Both client and server are generating RSA key-pair and they intend to send the public key (post conversion to strings), to each other, in a localhost environment, using Client-Server model, on a button click from my Android app.

Here is my code, which is seeming to work in Telnet, however, it is not the same when it comes to Android. In other words, it is printing the statements I put in to verify failures.

**MainActivity.java file**:

```
package com.avineshwar.secureclient;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private Button button;
    private TextView textView;
    private String messsage;

    SecureRandom random;
    KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator;
    KeyPair keyPair;
    PrivateKey privateKey;
    PublicKey publicKey;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    String server = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          random = new SecureRandom();
                                          keyPairGenerator = null;
                                          try {
                                              keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                                          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                                              e.printStackTrace();
                                          }
                                          keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, random);
                                          keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
                                          privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
                                          publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
                                          messsage = String.valueOf(publicKey);
                                          SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                                          sendMessageTask.execute();
                                          if (server == null || server == "null") {
                                              server = "null";
                                              textView.setText(server);
                                          } else {
                                              textView.setText(server);
                                          }

                                      }
                                  }

        );
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                try {
                    client = new Socket("192.168.1.169", 4444); // connect to the server
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                printwriter = null;
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(messsage);

                inputStreamReader = null;
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                server = bufferedReader.readLine();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                while ((server = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(server + "\n");
                }
                server = stringBuilder.toString();
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

//@Override
//public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
// getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slimple_text_client, menu);
//   return true;
// }
}
```

**SecureServer.java file**:

```
import com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.Message;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.KeyGeneratorSpi;
import sun.nio.cs.Surrogate;

public class SecureServer {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048, random);
        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); // Server socket

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
        }

        System.out.println("Server started listening on the port 4444");

        while (true) {
            try {

                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
                inputStreamReader = null;
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                if (message == null || message == "null") {
                    message = "null";
                }
                System.out.println(message);
                PrintWriter out = null;
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                message = publicKey.toString();
                out.write(message);
                System.out.println(message);
                out.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Press to send RSA key"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.avineshwar.secureclient">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do understand one thing though, however, I am not sure if it is correct and that is until I don't close my **PrintWriter object** in the Android app, the data is not going to be reflected on the server side, however, even if I do that, it is just solving one part of the scene, i.e., data from Android to server. I am not sure about any specific manner of collecting the data being sent from server though it is working for Telnet, i.e., both to and fro.

In **SecureServer.java** file, this statement,

```
inputStreamReader.close();
```

If put before these statements,

```
out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
message = publicKey.toString();
out.write(message);
System.out.println(message);
```

is throwing a handled IOException, which says **Problem in message reading**.

Apart from this, what I have observed is that in case we are writing anything to a socket, the *"output to socket" stream* has to be immediately closed as well, i.e., we cannot deal with any other stream related to that socket until this stream is closed.

**A higher-level view of, my experience with, and approach to, the problem**:

- Program structure has to be in opposite direction.
- When client sends something, server should be in a receiving state and vice-versa.
- For that to be possible, any previous state has to be completed.
- My client is sending some data to server (which is being received as well).
- Server on receiving that data, wants to send some data back.
- For that, server has to open an output stream for the same socket through which he read the data. I assume we shouldn't close the previously opened input stream before doing this because it never worked for me that way.
- Server does the job of creating an input stream and then writing the data to the input stream.
- However, parallely, in the client Android app, it is also expecting the data from server at socket's input stream. I assumed when server will send the data, this stream will receive it (and display it in a text view widget).
- Right now, this idea/implementation seeming to work for Telnet (client) and Server.
- In the past, data transfer from server to Android app has worked for me though. If there is just one-way transfer from server to client (Android app), it works.

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace anytime you have a problem where an exception is thrown

Comment: @VinceEmigh Thank you for your reply. There is no error as such. That was me playing around with the code without having a good idea what of I should actually do. I do have a clear approach in my mind what I want to do, however, the way it needs to be glued together is not as clear.

What is happening is that the communication seems to work when Telnet is acting as a client, however, it isn't the case when Android app is the client. Probably what I doubt is either I am doings things which isn't possible in one click event, or I am doing it wrong.